# What if Roulette Wheel Selection returns the same parent?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm using roulette wheel selection, and I'm wondering - what happens if when we are trying to breed a child, the same parent is selected? Do we still do crossover since the resulting child will be the same as the parent?

```
breedChild: function() {

  //blah blah blah
  //blah blah blah
  //blah blah blah

  var mom = this.rouletteWheelSelection(),
    dad = this.rouletteWheelSelection();
}



rouletteWheelSelection: function() {
  var total = 0,
    //totalFitnessScore is precalculated, and represents the sum of all the fitness scores in current population
    threshold = totalFitnessScore * Math.random();

  for (var i = 0; i < genomesArr.length; i++) {
    total += genomesArr[i].fitnessScore;

    if (total >= threshold) break;
  };

  return genomesArr[i];
}
```

Comment: This isn't a *programming* problem. Your question isn't related to the act of programming or tools used for programming.

Comment: @meagar It's a question asking for clarification on an algorithm. It's on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crossover wouldn't make a difference, but selecting the same parents should be so infrequent that checking if the parents are the same for each child produced would be more computationally expensive than performing the crossover in such cases - if it's not then your gene pool is going to be too small to produce effective results. On a side note, a child could still differ from it's parent if a mutation is introduced.

Comment: It's worth adding, there are GAs that use some form of incest prevention to prevent parents from mating if they're identical or even just too similar. CHC is perhaps the best known such method. So while it's not worth worrying about special-casing for picking the same parent twice, it might be worth building an algorithm that prevents this as part of a larger diversity preservation scheme.